# Image in the exe , wpf,c# .Net , vs2008

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image

I have a wpf application. 
I want to show two images on two buttons , and i would like to take to another computer only the exe file without those images. What is the best way to do it?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add those images to the resources of the project, this way images become the part of the assembly. Have a look at [Using Project Resources in WPF](http://blog.nostatic.org/2007/08/using-project-resources-in-wpf.html)

Comment: Thank you very much , it is a very simple and clear way to do it(and this is what i whant) , I didn't have any luck this morning in google search...